# What is the most pythonic way to join or construct paths?

Tags: python

Is it using the os.path.join() method, or concatenating strings? Examples:

```
fullpath1 = os.path.join(dir, subdir)
fullpath2 = os.path.join(dir, "subdir")
fullpath3 = os.path.join("dir", subdir)
fullpath4 = os.path.join(os.path.join(dir, subdir1), subdir2)
etc
```

or

```
fullpath1 = dir + "\\" + subdir
fullpath2 = dir + "\\" + "subdir"
fullpath3 = "dir" + "\\" + subdir
fullpath4 = dir + "\\" + subdir1 + \\" + subdir2"
etc
```

Edit with some more info.
This is a disagreement between a colleague and I. He insists the second method is "purer", while I insist using the built in functions are actually "purer" as it would make it more pythonic, and of course it makes the path handling OS-independent.

We tried searching to see if this question had been answered before, either here in SO or elsewhere, but found nothing

Comment: Definitely the first way. The added advantage of this approach is you can be sure it is platform independent.

Comment: Python does have a specific function for it, *and* it looks cleaner than the backslash hell, *and* you've introduced syntax errors through incorrect manual quoting… The question answers itself.

Comment: BTW, `os.path.joind(os.path.join(dir, subdir1), subdir2)` should be `os.path.join(dir, subdir1, subdir2)`.

Comment: In modern versions of Python the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module is the de-facto best practice

Comment: and avoid using built-in command names as your variables - dir is such example (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: thanks all for the comments, this is a bit of a war i'm having with a colleague who insists the 2nd way is "purer". Thanks for the new in 3.4 lib. The dir and subdir variable names were just for the pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion (I know, no one asked) it is indeed using `Path` from `pathlib`

```
import pathlib
folder = pathlib.Path('path/to/folder')
subfolder = folder / 'subfolder'

file = subfolder / 'file1.txt'
```

Please read into `pathlib` for more useful functions, one I often use is `resolve` and `folder.exists()` to check if a folder exist or `subfolder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)` to create a new folder including its parents. Those are random examples, the module can do a lot more.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the first method using `os.join()`.

A second option is to use the Pathlib module as @DeepSpace suggested.

But the other option is way worse and harder to read so you shouldn't use it.